# Set SharePoint Value using a Button

Tags: sharepoint

In SP 2007, is there a way if I have a list of tasks with standard fields eg: [Title], [Assigned to], [% Complete] etc I could use some form of JavaScript / Calculated Column to insert a button on each row, that when clicked would set the % Complete value for that row to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the above would be possible but you can add a custom action to ECB Menu and invoke JavaScript wherein you can use the List Web Service to perform the update.

Comment: Hi - thanks for that. I don't have access to SP Designer though, so I am very limited in my options unfortunately. To be honest I'm not sure what Javascript I would use to update the list services anyways. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: [<CustomAction>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194%28v=office.12%29.aspx) has a child  element <UrlAction>. In this you can invoke the JavaScript code. Another option - If you can attach a code behind, you can simplify it by calling a custom page with the item id and list id and there you can complete the action.